# Получение label поля option

Tags: javascript

У меня есть форма

```
<select name="city" id="city">
<option value=0>Санкт-Питербург</option>
<option value=1>Москва</option>
</select>
```

Чтобы получить значение, с помощью jQuery, нужно сделать так $('#city').val();
это не проблема. А как мне получить сами слова Санкт-Питербург, или Москва, вместо цифр 0 или 1?

Сразу оговорю что ничего в форме менять нельзя, и обрабатывать типа

```
 if(this.value==0){alert('Спб');} else if(this.value==1){alert('Мск')}
```

тоже, т.к. в форме может быть больше 20 элементов, все не обработаешь, нужно напрямую получить этот label.
Подскажите как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну раз вы про jquery тогда так:

```
$(":selected",this).text();
```

Comment: Пробовал. он вывел мне всё в одну строку 

Санкт-Петербург Москва

А как сделать только то, что было выбрано. ищу вот ответ.

Comment: Всё нашёл)))

`$('#city option:selected').text();`

Comment: я поправил